# Applying .diff in source tree of Mac

Tags: macos, diff, atlassian-sourcetree

I use a mac and I have a `.diff` file that is to be applied from Sourcetree.

Can someone help me with the steps for the same?

Answer (score 49):

I finally found the answer to this for **MAC**.

`Sourcetree -> Actions -> Apply Patch -> Browse -> (Choose File) -> Apply`

You can import the `.diff` file. Its similar to how we apply the regular patch.

Comment: its the same for the windows version of Sourcetree!